# how to calculate correlation with groupby for n rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 code    tank     var     nozzle_1    nozzle_2     nozzle_3
 123     1        23.34   12.23       54.56        12.22
 123     1        22.32   11.32       7.89         3.45
 123     1        21.22   19.93       5.54         5.66
 123     1        21.34   12.23       54.56        22.22
 123     1        32.32   13.32       4.89         32.45
 123     1        32.22   29.93       23.54        23.66
 123     2        23.34   12.23       54.56        12.22
 123     2        22.32   11.32       7.89         3.45
 123     2        21.22   19.93       5.54         5.66
 123     2        21.34   12.23       54.56        22.22
 123     2        32.32   13.32       4.89         32.45
 123     2        32.22   29.93       23.54        23.66
```

I want to find correlation of nozzle_1, nozzle_2, nozzle_3 with var column grouping by tank and taking correlation for every 3 rows

My desired dataframe would be

```
 code    tank     nozzle_1    nozzle_2     nozzle_3
 123     1        0.20        0.30         0.23 
 123     1        0.12        0.08         0.12
 123     2        0.14        0.12         0.01
 123     2        0.15        0.04         0.13
```

I am doing following with pandas

```
cols= df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat='nozzle_\d+$', regex=True)] 
cols= np.array(cols)


def corrVar(df, cols):
        for col in cols_to_scale:
            for i in range(0, df.shape[0], 3):
                df[col] = df.groupby('tank')[col, 'var'].corr()
        return df
```

test =  corrVar(df, cols)

But, it is not giving me desired results. How can we do it in pandas?

Comment: why do you have three values for correlation, i don't get it

Comment: I have many values, but just for question I have limited it to 3

Answer (score 0):

There is not straightforward solution for this, so here's my breakdown:

1. We get the column indices of columns that start with `nozzle`
2. We get column index of column `var`
3. `GroupBy` on `code, tank` and calculate the correlation for the **first half** of the dataframe for each `nozzle` column
4. Do the same but for the **second half**
5. `Concat` both halfs on top of each other as a `final` dataframe

```
cols_idx = [df.columns.get_loc(c) for c in df.filter(like='nozzle').columns]
var_idx = df.columns.get_loc('var')

df1 = pd.concat([
    df.groupby(['code','tank']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:len(x)//2, var_idx].corr(x.iloc[:len(x)//2, idx])) for idx in cols_idx
], axis=1).reset_index()

df2 = pd.concat([
    df.groupby(['code','tank']).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[len(x)//2:, var_idx].corr(x.iloc[len(x)//2:, idx])) for idx in cols_idx
], axis=1).reset_index()


df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_values('tank').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
   code  tank         0         1         2
0   123     1 -0.826376  0.876202  0.703793
1   123     1  0.540176 -0.931286  0.614626
2   123     2 -0.826376  0.876202  0.703793
3   123     2  0.540176 -0.931286  0.614626
```

---

If you want to rename the columns correctly

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Actually in my real dataframe, I want to calculate correlation on every 100 rows. In that case, what changes I have to make?

Comment: Is each `tank` group the same size, or do they differ?

Comment: Yes, each tank group the same size of 100 rows and in example I have given it 3.

Comment: Then this should work, it's not hardcoded that it takes `3` rows, it splits each `tank` group in half. So as you can see, your tank groups are length `6` so it takes the top 3 rows and bottom 3 rows. This should generalize well for bigger datasets.

Comment: e.g. If I have 500 rows, then I should have 5 correlations. Every 100 rows one correlation.

Comment: Your code is dividing the dataframe in 2 equal parts, but I want to calculate correlation for every 100 rows. In example due to space limitations I have mentioned on every 3 rows.

Comment: I understand what you want, but that makes your question quite more complex and I cant fix my answer with a simple edit. I see this question as answered, feel free to ask a new question and format your question correct this time. You can link it here and I try to answer it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd


data = [
        [ 123, 1, 23.34, 12.23, 54.56, 12.22 ],
        [ 123, 1, 22.32, 11.32, 7.89,  3.45  ],
        [ 123, 1, 21.22, 19.93, 5.54,  5.66  ],
        [ 123, 1, 21.34, 12.23, 54.56, 22.22 ],
        [ 123, 1, 32.32, 13.32, 4.89,  32.45 ],
        [ 123, 1, 32.22, 29.93, 23.54, 23.66 ],
        [ 123, 2, 23.34, 12.23, 54.56, 12.22 ],
        [ 123, 2, 22.32, 11.32, 7.89,  3.45  ],
        [ 123, 2, 21.22, 19.93, 5.54,  5.66  ],
        [ 123, 2, 21.34, 12.23, 54.56, 22.22 ],
        [ 123, 2, 32.32, 13.32, 4.89,  32.45 ],
        [ 123, 2, 32.22, 29.93, 23.54, 23.66 ]
]

columns = ['code', 'tank',  'var',  'nozzle_1', 'nozzle_2',  'nozzle_3']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

print(df[['tank', 'var',  'nozzle_1', 'nozzle_2',  'nozzle_3']].groupby(['tank']).corr())


# ------------------------------------------------------
# RESULT:
#                     var  nozzle_1  nozzle_2  nozzle_3
# tank                                                 
# 1    var       1.000000  0.501164 -0.309435  0.761017
#      nozzle_1  0.501164  1.000000 -0.214982  0.168518
#      nozzle_2 -0.309435 -0.214982  1.000000  0.107815
#      nozzle_3  0.761017  0.168518  0.107815  1.000000
# 2    var       1.000000  0.501164 -0.309435  0.761017
#      nozzle_1  0.501164  1.000000 -0.214982  0.168518
#      nozzle_2 -0.309435 -0.214982  1.000000  0.107815
#      nozzle_3  0.761017  0.168518  0.107815  1.000000
```